# how to set include paths with autotools

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, include-path

I'm working on a C++ project that uses `autoconf` & `automake`, and I'm struggling to correctly set up the include paths in `*CPPFLAGS`. I've read about 3 hours worth of documents, and I can't figure it out yet. I'm not looking for a hack, but for the correct way to do this. Here is my conundrum.

As I see it, there are 3 completely different sources for include paths:

1. External libraries that must be installed along with my package, which are configured by `configure --with-XXX=<PATH>`.
2. Within my package, some source files use `#include <file.h>` even when `file.h` is part of the package, so to compile them, I must set the include path correctly. (Note, it's not an option to edit all these files.)
3. Whimsical (or not) standards specify the user must be allowed to specify their own (extra) include paths. That is, I shouldn't be setting `CPPFLAGS` at all.

In my current setup:

- Type 1 paths are set inside `configure.ac` by `AC_SUBST(CPPFLAGS, "$CPPFLAGS -I<path>")`.
- Type 2 paths are set inside `Makefile.am` by `test_CPPFLAGS = -I<path>`.
- Type 3 cannot be set. More exactly, if the user sets `CPPFLAGS` before running `make`, this overrides Type 1 settings, causing compilation to fail. Of course, the user could try to use `CXXFLAGS` instead, but that one has a different use (remember, I'm asking for the correct way to do this, not a hack).

I tried to fix this by setting Type 1 paths using `AM_CPPFLAGS` inside `configure.ac`. (For reference: if you set `AM_CPPFLAGS` instead of `CPPFLAGS`, but you still need to run some checks such as `AC_CHECK_HEADERS`, you need to temporarily set `CPPFLAGS` and then revert it for the checks to work; this is explained [here](http://www.bioinf.uni-freiburg.de/~mmann/HowTo/automake.html#extLibCheck).) This frees up `CPPFLAGS` for Type 3 paths, but unfortunately the compilation fails because the `Makefile`-s that gets produced by `configure` will only use `AM_CPPFLAGS` if no specialized `<target>_CPPFLAGS` exists. So, if `test_CPPFLAGS` exists with a Type 2 path, compiling `test` will fail because it doesn't get the Type 1 path.

A fix would be to specify inside `Makefile.am` to always use `AM_CPPFLAGS`. But is this "by the book"? Can I do this in a global way, or do I have to edit every single `target_CPPFLAGS`? Is there another "correct" solution?

Comment: By "whimsical", do you include the official autoconf documentation which clearly states that CPPFLAGS is a user variable should not be modified by the maintainer?  (See section 4.8.1 at http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html)

Comment: Although a less ambiguous example from the official automake documentation may be clearer, which states "You should never redefine a user variable such as CPPFLAGS in Makefile.am." in section 27.6 at http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Flag-Variables-Ordering.html#Flag-Variables-Ordering

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I know it's difficult to get a straight answer from the autotools manuals. There are a couple of good start-to-finish tutorials [here](https://autotools.io/) and [here](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool).

There isn't a standard variable for package-specific `*CPPFLAGS` in autoconf. `configure` can be invoked with `CPPFLAGS=...`, and automake will add this `CPPFLAGS` to the relevant makefile rules - search for `CPPFLAGS` in a `Makefile.in` file for examples. For that reason, I suggest that you *not* use this variable for anything else.

Add flags in `Makefile.am` to the `AM_CPPFLAGS` variable (the default for all preprocessor calls) or override individual preprocessor flags with `target_CPPFLAGS`. In the example of a 3rd party library, it's best to use a name like: `FOO_CPPFLAGS` to hold preprocessor options, e.g.,

```
FOO_CPPFLAGS="-I${FOO_DIR}/include -DFOO_BAR=1"
...
AC_SUBST(FOO_CPPFLAGS)
```

and in the `Makefile.am` :

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir) $(FOO_CPPFLAGS)
# or:
target_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir) $(FOO_CPPFLAGS)
```

The `top_srcdir` variable is defined by `configure` - I use it to illustrate the 2nd case. Let's say you have `file.h` in another directory `other`, under the top-level directory. `-I$(top_srcdir)` allows you to include it as `<other/file.h>`. Alternatively, `-I$(top_srcdir)/other` would allow you to include it as `<file.h>`.

Another useful [preset variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Preset-Output-Variables) is `srcdir` - the current directory. `-I$(srcdir)` is added to `AM_CPPFLAGS` *by default*. So if `file.h` is in the current directory you can include it with `<file.h>` or even `"file.h"`. If `other` was a 'sibling' directory, `-I$(srcdir)/..` would allow you to include `<other/file.h>`, and `-I$(srcdir)/../other` would allow `<file.h>`.

---

I'd also add that some packages install a pkg-config `.pc` file. Provided the installation of pkg-config is set up to search the right directories, you might find the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro very useful.

Comment: Another is `$(builddir)` or `$(top_builddir)` which is apparently meant to be used for any files that is generated during a build.